# spicy angularjs regex

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I've been working on a regex problem for angularJs ng-pattern which needs:

1. Cannot be blanks
2. A minimum of 1 character and a maximum of 32 characters
3. Spaces ONLY are not allowed
4. Acceptable special characters(!@#$%&*-+=[]:;',.? )
5. The answer is not case sensitive
6. Combination of &# is not allowed
7. Spaces at the beginning and the end of the answer should be trimmed.

This is my solution which covers all requirement but 6th:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%& *+=[\]:;',.?-])|(^\s*$)
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what "5. The answer is not case sensitive" means?

Comment: I think you need `/^(?!\s*$)(?:(?!&#)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;',.?\s-]){1,32}$/`. However, I have no idea what your Req. 7 means. `ng-pattern`  does not trim input text.

Comment: the only one that I couldn't figure out is #6 req. I can do 'string'.trim() to handle #7. And for #5, a-zA-Z covers that.

Comment: Ok, did you try my suggestion? See https://regex101.com/r/AuTmSj/1. It can also be [`^(?!\s*$)(?!.*&#)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;',.?\s-]{1,32}$`](https://regex101.com/r/AuTmSj/2)

Comment: Omg, that works great. Thank you, Wiktor. So, put the ?! at the beginning means to match the negate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!\s*$)(?!.*&#)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;',.?\s-]{1,32}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AuTmSj/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s*$)` - no 0+ whitespaces from start till end of string allowed
- `(?!.*&#)` - no `&#` allowed after any 0+ chars
- `[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;',.?\s-]{1,32}` - 1 to 32 allowed chars: ASCII digits, letters, whitespaces and some punctuation/symbols
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for the help, just one more question. what about the #& combination? now, the &# combination is working now, but I tried to add another group of (?!#&), but it didn't work.

Comment: figure it out. /^(?!\s*$)(?:(?!&#|#&)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;’,.?\s-])+$/, there you go.

Comment: @user1070111 Or `/^(?!\s*$)(?!.*#&)(?!.*&#)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*+=[\]:;',.?\s-]{1,32}$/`